# SQL smart replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have records in a SQL Server 2005 database that contain something like this:

```
longlongLongText###abcdefg###longlongLongText
```

(it can be different letters in each record and might be more or less letters. The pattern ###abcdefg### will be a part of a long string.)

I want to update the records so i'll keep only the first 3 letters. The result will be

```
longlongLongText###abc###longlongLongText
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it always have 3 sharps at the beginning and 3 at the end?

Comment: Yes. Always 3 ###.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How is it possible :)

Comment: So, you have a string which contains several substrings with 3 sharps, some data and again 3 sharps. Right?

Comment: Yes! several substrings with 3 sharps.

Comment: *Several* substrings with 3 sharps? So a string can look like this: `'abc###defgh###hijklm###nopqrs###tuvwxyz'` and you want this to become `'abc###def###hijklm###nop###tuvwxyz'`?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question with a better explanation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

**Replace "col1" with your column name.**

```
update yourtable
        SET col1 = substring(col1,0,charindex('###',col1)-1)+substring(col1,charindex('###',col1),6)+ substring(col1,CHARINDEX('###',col1,(charindex('###',col1)+1)), (len(col1)-CHARINDEX('###',col1,(charindex('###',col1)))))
```

[here](http://rextester.com/IRZM68926) you can see and test

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Update YourTable

Set YourField = left(YourField,CHARINDEX('###', YourField)-1) + substring(YourField, CHARINDEX('###', YourField),6) + right(YourField, len(YourField) - CHARINDEX('###', YourField) - 8)

where CHARINDEX('###', YourField)>0
```

-The left function will return the left part of your long string until it reaches '###'

-The substring function will return the substring starting from the first '###' and containing your first 3 caracters.

-the right function will return the right substring starting from the second '###'

You can try it here: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/10646)

Comment: But it's a part of a long string. I don't want to keep just the Left 6.

Comment: You said you only want to keep the first 3 letters after the sharps, so 3 sharps and 3 letters is 6.

Comment: That's true, but I also said "It will be a part of a long string".

Comment: Ah ok, got you, maybe it's better if you can update your post with an example of these long strings.

Comment: I think this way will work but will drop the part of the string that's after the pattern.

Comment: hmmm I think I just understood your problem :D, let me fix it again

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select left(str, 6) + '###'
```

Or alternatively:

```
select '###' + left(replace(str, '#', ''), 3) + '###'
```

This will work better if there are only one or two letters in the middle.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 6 instead of 7?

Answer (score 0):

Create simple function like following:

```
create function fnReplaceByPattern(@s varchar(max)) returns varchar(max)
begin
    declare @pos int = 1;
    declare @len int = len(@s);

    declare @result varchar(max) = '';

    while @pos < @len
    begin
        declare @start int = charindex('###', @s, @pos);
        declare @end int = charindex('###', @s, @start + 3);

        if @start != 0 and @end != 0
        begin
            set @result += substring(@s, @pos, @start - @pos + 6) + '###';
            set @pos = @end + 3;
        end
        else
        begin
            set @result += substring(@s, @pos, @len - @pos + 1);
            set @pos = @len;
        end
    end

    return @result
end
```

And then use `update T1 set Data = dbo.fnReplaceByPattern(Data)`